# Setting an object as a new property in another object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have basically created a main object like below:

```
var seriesOptions = {
y: +parseFloat($(this).find('y').text()).toFixed(2),
color: colors[index],
level : dlevel
};
```

Now I keep adding new property with values to the above object like:

```
var drilldown {
name : $(series).children('name').text(),
level : dlevel + 1,
color: colors[index]
};

var data {
values : []
}

for .. each 
  data.values.push(..)

drilldown['data'] = data;
seriesOptions['drilldown'] = drilldown;
```

The above code goes in an main for .. each loop. So when the main loop ends I have something like below object layout:

```
seriesOptions
             drilldown
                      data
                          drilldown
                                  data
......................................
```

Now I want to access the last data node of a particular name in seriesOptions - as per example above for last 'drilldown' note in seriesOptions would be **seriesOptions.drilldown.data.drilldown** - how can I access the last object of type data in seriesOptions? I want to add another property and its values to it like:

```
seriesOptions
             drilldown
                      data
                          drilldown
                                  data
                                  <finalobject>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you asking this

http://api.jquery.com/last-child-selector/

Comment: DOM manipulation on JavaScript objects? Even if it were a collection of DOM objects, `:last-child` will **not** select the deepest node in the tree.

Comment: I think **$(seriestemp).last('drilldown')** should give me the last drilldown node?

Comment: it is like a search on a common attribute fild the last..not actually last child. upvote me and accept answer and continue to work